# Test actors: receive exactly N messages

Tags: scala, akka, actor, akka-testkit

I'm testing an application with Akka actors. I'm using Test probes. I want to verify that the probe receives EXACTLY 10 messages of the same type. One solution could be to write 10 times:

```
probe.expectMsg(20 seconds, Done)
```

But I would prefer a more general solution (for example I'd test my application also for n=100).
I also tried probe.receiveN(10, 20 seconds) but if I receive more than 10 elements the test doesn't fail. Instead I want it to fail in this case. Is there a solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [Akka Documentation:](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/testing.html)

```
expectMsgAllOf[T](d: Duration, obj: T*): Seq[T]
```

> A number of objects matching the size of the supplied object array
>   must be received within the given time, and for each of the given
>   objects there must exist at least one among the received ones which
>   equals (compared with ==) it. The full sequence of received objects is
>   returned.

Then use `expectNoMsg(d: Duration)` to make sure there is exactly the number required.

With your code:

```
val numberOfMessages = 10
probe.expectMsgAllOf(20 seconds, Array.fill(numberOfMessages)(Done))
probe.expectNoMsg(20 seconds)
```

Comment: This is not precisely what I need. I want to receive EXACTLY 10 messages (no less, no more). With your solution, test fails when I receive less than 10 messages but it passes with > 10 messages received. Finally I found the solution: i put probe.expectNoMsg() just after your expectMsgAllOf().